# Node/Express project using EJS partials and angular: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I feel like I have completely missed something here but I am trying to use ejs partials in a single page angular app. I keep getting a Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined in my partial. I think this may have something to do with using ejs partials instead of using ng-include, however I have not had any luck in playing with that. Any help would be amazing.

**app.js**

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('dashboard', []);

  app.controller('ItemController', function(){
    this.item = items;
  });

  //need to loop through items in DB for now using these test objects
  var items = [
    {
      name : 'name1',//query to db for name goes here
      stock : '4',//query to db
      img : '/images/bb-logo.png'//query to db
    },
    {
      name : 'name2',//query to db for name goes here
      stock : '6',//query to db
      img : '/images/bb-logo.png'//query to db
    }
  ];

})();
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="dashboard">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href='/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href='/libs/foundation/css/foundation.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href='/stylesheets/style.css'>
  <!-- include angular here -->
  <script type="text/javascript" href='/libs/angular/angular.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href='/libs/modernizer/modernizer.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/angularApp.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <% include partials/topbar %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns etsy-container">
      <% include partials/etsy-container %>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <% include partials/amazon-container %>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**/amazong-container**

```
<div class='store-container'>
  <h1 class="left">Amazon</h1>
  <span class="store-utility-icons"><i class="fa fa-refresh right"></i><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o right"></i></span>
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <% include /item %>
</div>
```

**/item.ejs**

```
<div ng-controller="ItemController as store" >
  <div ng-repeat="item in store.items">
    <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" />
    <p>{{item.name}} <i> Stock level: {{item.stock}}</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you include Angular is wrong. You have

```
<script type="text/javascript" href='/libs/angular/angular.js'></script>
```

but it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

So you have to use `src` instead of `href`. Looks like a typical copy/paste error. So, in the end, this has nothing to do with EJS or using partials, it's just wrong HTML ;-).

PS: Apart from that, you're using single quotes for attributes in HTML. Go with double quotes all the times, as this is the usual and common way to do it.

PPS: The same applies to the line where you try to load Modernizr.